# How to transfer data with Intents

Tags: android, android-scripting

I am building an application that has 2 classes
- Buttons_Class
- Display_Class
I want to keep them as separate classes.
When the user clicks on a button the OnClick routine in the Buttons_Class creates an intent and a bundle and starts the Display_Class activity. This is working fine. The Display_Class gets the information and displays it in a TextView.

What needs to happen next? If the user clicks on a second button, does the Display_Activity need to be recreated? Does a new intend need to be created? How does the information go from one activity to the next every time the user clicks on a button.
Any examples will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible dublicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-to-pass-data-between-activities-in-android

Comment: and a hint: CamelCase should be used in Java, for variable names and also for classnames. underscore is valid, but not really used in any of the recommended coding styles from sun and/or google

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If the user clicks on a second button, does the Display_Activity need to be recreated?

When you call `startActivity()`, by default, it creates a new instance of the activity. You can control that with flags on the Intent if you want, such as `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT`.

> Does a new intend need to be created?

If you are starting a different activity, yes. If you are starting another copy of `Display_Activity`, perhaps not.